# I am not able to install MySQL server

Tags: 16.04, apt, software-installation, mysql

I am getting the following error while installing MySQL-server:

```
E: Package 'mysql-server-core-5.5' has no installation candidate.
```

I tried many steps like adding repositories and installing it again, but no use. Can anyone give the solution?

Answer (score 1):

What was the command that you used to install it? I tried:

```
sudo apt install mysql-server
```

and it worked fine however when I tried:

```
sudo apt install mysql-server-core
```

it gave me the response

```
E: Unable to locate package mysql-server-core
```

Try the first command and see if that works.